# Define an SQL constraint depending on more than one attribute

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, ddl

I have this defined type and table:

```
CREATE TYPE emp_role AS ENUM ('Manager','Developer','Accountant','Secretary');
CREATE TABLE employees (
employee_id int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
lastname text NOT NULL,
firstname text NOT NULL,
address text NOT NULL,
hire_date date NOT NULL,
salary numeric NOT NULL CHECK(salary > 1.500), 
emp_role emp_role,
department_id int NOT NULL
);
```

I want to create a constraint on this table, without modifying its definition, that depends at the same time on the attributes `hire_date`, `salary`and `emp_role`, this means for example that employees with `emp_role` of `Manager` hired after `2019-21-11` can't have `salary`bigger than `15.000`so a query like this should return an error:

```
INSERT INTO employees VALUES(2,'foo','bar','foostreet','2019-12-20',18.0000,'Manager',3);
```

I'm not familiar with how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a multi-column check constraint as follows:

```
CREATE TYPE emp_role AS ENUM ('Manager','Developer','Accountant','Secretary');

CREATE TABLE employees (
    employee_id int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    lastname text NOT NULL,
    firstname text NOT NULL,
    address text NOT NULL,
    hire_date date NOT NULL,
    salary numeric NOT NULL CHECK(salary > 1500), 
    emp_role emp_role,
    department_id int NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT CK_employee CHECK (
        NOT(
            emp_role = 'Manager' 
            AND hire_date > DATE'2019-11-21' 
            AND salary > 15000
        )
    )
);
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bb5357a8b65bd0963eace0e3db173c1d)**

```
INSERT INTO employees VALUES(2,'foo','bar','foostreet','2019-12-20',180000,'Manager',3);
```

```
ERROR:  new row for relation "employees" violates check constraint "ck_employee"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, foo, bar, foostreet, 2019-12-20, 180000, Manager, 3).
```

```
INSERT INTO employees VALUES(2,'foo','bar','foostreet','2019-12-20',1,'Developer',3);
```

```
ERROR:  new row for relation "employees" violates check constraint "employees_salary_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, foo, bar, foostreet, 2019-12-20, 1, Developer, 3).
```

Comment: `1.500` should be `15000` because of "*can't have salarybigger than 15.000*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: yes indeed, original code does not match the text of the question. I modified that.

Comment: I think it needs to be an OR condition. If it's a manager it can't be higher than 15000 but if it's a regular employee it should be higher than 1.5 (which is the original check constraint in the question)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: or we should just keep the original check constraint on the `salary` > 1.5?

Comment: This condition is: no employee in general can be paid less than 1.500 but if it's a manager employed after a certain date, he can be paid at most 15.000

Comment: @aniani2020: in SQL `1.500` means "one point five" (=one and a half), **not** one thousand five hundred

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name the numbers are no problem, 1.5 is interpreted as 1500 when reading the table

Comment: @aniani2020: the answer does what you want. The check constraint on `salary` forbids salaries lower than 1500 (for all types of employees), and the multi-column constraint prevents managers hired after the given date to have a salary higher than 18000.